# When do authentication cookie remove on browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, session-cookies

I have an MVC 4 application. I'm so curious on what particular code triggers the removal of .ASPXAUTH cookie authentication that is set on my browser.
I tried to debug each line to determine which of my code triggers the removing of the ticket on my browser but it seems that non of my codes below do that,I always check on my browser whether the authentication ticket is still there on every lines of code I step into upon debugging. And I found out that the .ASPXAUTH cookie is only removed when it is redirected to other page. Is there any explanation on this?? Because I am planning to set a cookie or session on browser and remove it afterwards. :)

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                HttpRuntime.Close();
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(User.Identity.Name, false);

            if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
                {
                    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this below link to get an exact idea of form authentication mechanism in MVC

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx